# Visual Studio Command Compiler Forces 64 Bit Compile

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, 32bit-64bit, scons

I am attempting to build an executable and some associated dlls in Windows VS Command Prompt.  The project comes with a scons file, so I simply type scons in a VS Cmd Prompt.

The executable is being built inside an "x86" VS Cmd Prompt.  However, when run the executable is not 32 bit (confirmed with Task Manager.)  My coworker builds the same exact project on his 64 bit machine, using the scons file, and his executable is 32 bit on my computer. (confirmed with Task Manager once again)

The dll's are being loaded by a 32 bit JVM, and they throw an error as they are 64 bit.  My coworkers dll's do not.

**We cannot figure out why my computer is forcing a 64 bit build inside the "x86" VS environment.  Does anyone have any suggestions?**

P.S. - I have MS VS 2010 and he has the MS VS 2010 Express.

P.S.S. - I have 64 bit python, and thus my scons is also 64 bit.  However, so does my coworker though.

Comment: VS Express doesn't do 64-bit builds, so that explains why your co-workers build is 32-bit.  Type `cl` at the VS command-prompt on your PC.  The first line of output should end with either `for 80x86` or `for x64`.

Comment: It says 32 bit for 80x86

Comment: There's no flags for cl that I could find that force 32 bit, do you know of any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scons would normally determine what tool-chain (i.e., compiler) to use (if you don't specify it explicitly) based on what it can find installed.

A Visual Studio 2010 *Express* can only build 32-bit binaries - even on a 64-bit Windows - so that is what Scons would do. With a Visual Studio 2010 'non-express' in which both 32- and 64-bit compilers are available, Scons would presumably go for a 64-bit build on a 64-bit Windows.

To specify a 32- or 64-bit build of a Scons project, you can set `TARGET_ARCH` to 'x86' or 'x86_64', respectively. See also Scons [Construction Variables](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user.html#app-variables).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution to esskov's, you can force SCons to use your environment's `PATH` variable, which will make it use the same compiler that you get when you type `cl` at the command prompt (which can be set correctly by running the appropriate command prompt shortcut provided by Visual Studio). To do this, propagate the external environment's PATH variable into your SCons construction environment, e.g.:

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})
```

See [this FAQ entry](http://www.scons.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Why_doesn.27t_SCons_find_my_compiler.2BAC8-linker.2BAC8-etc..3F_I_can_execute_it_just_fine_from_the_command_line.) or [this section of the documentation](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idm15456856), and note the following warning:

> Of course, by propagating external environment variables into your
>   build, you're running the risk that a change in the external
>   environment will affect the build, possibly in unintended ways.